# Why does my cube 'jump' when I use CSS Transforms like rotateZ()?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have made a simple animation with a cube where it moves around the edges of a pane and am having troubles with how it rotates at each corner. For the first two corners it is fine and rotates smoothly, but for the others the cube seems to 'jump' before it moves back into position and continues moving again. For now I have just been using rotateZ() in my transforms.

I have tried playing around with things like the transform-origin, but I have not been able to find a solution myself. I am not sure what else to do as I do not know if there is a problem with the origin or if it is something like a sizing issue. I am still new to animating so please excuse any silly mistakes.

Please find the code below (HTML and CSS only so far).

```css
.perspective {
  background: gray;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: test 20s forwards;
}

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.cube__face--front {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: red;
}

.cube__face--right {
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: green;
}

.cube__face--back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: yellow;
}

.cube__face--left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: pink;
}

.cube__face--top {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: purple;
}

.cube__face--bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: orange;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  2% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  4% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(25px) translateY(75px) translateX(-50px);
  }
  6% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateY(150px) translateX(0px);
  }
  8% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateY(150px) translateX(0px);
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(25px) translateY(225px) translateX(-50px);
  }
  12% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateY(300px) translateX(0px);
  }
  14% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateY(300px) translateX(0px);
  }
  16% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(25px) translateY(375px) translateX(-50px);
  }
  18% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateY(450px) translateX(0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateY(450px) translateX(0px);
  }
  22% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(0px);
  }
  24% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(25px) translateX(-450px) translateY(75px);
  }
  26% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(150px);
  }
  28% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(150px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(25px) translateX(-450px) translateY(225px);
  }
  32% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(300px);
  }
  34% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(300px);
  }
  36% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(25px) translateX(-450px) translateY(375px);
  }
  38% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(450px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(450px);
  }
  /* X */
  42% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-500px);
  }
  44% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(75px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-425px);
  }
  46% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-350px);
  }
  48% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-350px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(75px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-275px);
  }
  52% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-200px);
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-200px);
  }
  56% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(75px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-125px);
  }
  58% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-50px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateX(-500px) translateY(-50px);
  }
  62% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateY(-500px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  64% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateY(-500px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(75px) translateY(-425px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  68% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateY(-350px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateY(-350px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  72% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(75px) translateY(-275px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  74% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateY(-200px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  76% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.75) translateZ(25px) translateY(-200px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  78% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.25) translateZ(75px) translateY(-125px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateZ(-270deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateY(-50px) translateX(-0px);
  }
  82% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg) scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.00) translateZ(25px) translateY(0px) translateX(-0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Cube Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="perspective">
      <div class="cube">
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--front"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--back"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--right"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--left"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--top"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems like this is being caused by your `transform-origin` staying at `0% 0%` even though the cube is rotating. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix that in a 3D plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the transformation origin is causing issues, since you're trying to both translate and rotate at the same time. Add an extra wrapper around your cube. Then, apply your translations to the outer div, and your rotations to your inner div.

I've simplified your example a bit for illustration, but you'll get the idea:

```css
.perspective {
  background: gray;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 25px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: translation 10s forwards;
}

.cube {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 25px 25px 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotation 10s forwards;
}

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.cube__face--front {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: red;
}

.cube__face--right {
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: green;
}

.cube__face--back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: yellow;
}

.cube__face--left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: pink;
}

.cube__face--top {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: purple;
}

.cube__face--bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: orange;
}

@keyframes translation {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 25px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 450px, 25px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(450px, 450px, 25px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(450px, 0, 25px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 25px);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Cube Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="perspective">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cube">
          <div class="cube__face cube__face--front"></div>
          <div class="cube__face cube__face--back"></div>
          <div class="cube__face cube__face--right"></div>
          <div class="cube__face cube__face--left"></div>
          <div class="cube__face cube__face--top"></div>
          <div class="cube__face cube__face--bottom"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the cube movements simple. I have adjusted the sides of the cube so that they are alreadyn in place without a cube transform.

Also, set the cube dimension to the seen cube dimension, and the center of movement in its center.

Then everything is easier, as can be seen in the cube animation

```css
.perspective {
  background: gray;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cube {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: test 20s linear forwards;
}

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.cube__face--front {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) translateZ(50px);
  background: red;
}

.cube__face--right {
  transform: translateZ(25px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: green;
}

.cube__face--back {
  transform: translateZ(25px) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: yellow;
}

.cube__face--left {
  transform: translateZ(25px) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: pink;
}

.cube__face--top {
  transform: translateZ(25px) rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: purple;
}

.cube__face--bottom {
  transform: translateZ(25px) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  background: orange;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px 0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(0px, 350px);
  }
  30% {
    transform:  translate(0px, 350px) rotateZ(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    transform:  translate(350px, 350px) rotateZ(-90deg);
  }
  55% {
    transform:  translate(350px, 350px) rotateZ(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform:  translate(350px, 0px) rotateZ(-180deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform:  translate(350px, 0px) rotateZ(-270deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform:  translate(0px, 0px) rotateZ(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translate(0px, 0px) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="perspective">
      <div class="cube">
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--front"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--back"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--right"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--left"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--top"></div>
        <div class="cube__face cube__face--bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```